# ASP.NET: Mapping 4 char code in URL as a query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I would like the asp.net app runtime to recognize the 'U9EO' code as a query string input (or other type of input if necessary) not a a folder:

```
website.com/U9EO
```

I know that there is a way to do this in the IIS 7 server, however, is there a method at the asp.net stack level?

The problem with routing is that the following won't work:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("",
            "{U9EO}",
            "~/Page.aspx?Code=U9EO"
            );
    }
```

The query string is simply lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

url routing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Such part of URL can be accessed in ASP.NET using [Request.PathInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo.aspx) property. I am certain that in url `http://example.com/xyz.aspx/U9EO`, ASP.NET run-time will give `/U9EO` as path info but not so sure about `http://example.com/U9EO` - especially if there exits such folder. You may try ASP.NET routing in such case.